# The Graphics Technology Browsers Use Under the Hood

Tags: opengl, browser, graphics, webkit, webgl

I know I have seen this somewhere for WebKit but can't seem to find it. I would also like to know for iOS/Android/IE the graphics technology used.

Basically, how they are implementing their 3D WebGL support, some library they are using on top of OpenGL perhaps.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thank you, removed that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every browser is different.

As of 2021 every browser uses ANGLE. Chromium (Chrome, Edge, Brave, etc...), Firefox, and Safari.

<s>As of 2018 Safari/Webkit calls into OpenGL on the Mac. I believe Chrome and Firefox use [ANGLE](https://github.com/google/angle). It used to be they used it only on Windows but as of their support for WebGL2 I believe both of them use it on all platforms. No idea what Edge or IE do.</s>

ANGLE itself can use OpenGL, OpenGL ES, DirectX 9, DirectX 11, DirectX 12, Metal, Vulkan and who knows in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for.